# When building a package, must i have a package.json file in my /src folder?

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I have several packages where there is a `package.json` file in root, as well as a `package.json` file in the `/src` folder. When I build, it is the `/src` file that is copied to the `/dist` folder. (and later published to Nexus).

What I am wondering is if this is the correct way to go, as when developing, I only change the outermost `/package.json file`. This means the /src file is "deprecated". And updating two files is a hassle.

Am I doing it the "correct" way, must i keep two files up to date? Or can I just use one file, the "root" one.

```
package.json
src/
    index.ts
    package.json
dist/
    index.d.ts
    index.js
    package.json //from src
```

Comment: Are you referring to the package.json file that each dependency module would have in it? Or the package.json that would be in your generated module as a dependent if someone used the module in their package? Not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: There is one package.json file in the root, telling npm what packages are needed when developing. There is another in the /src folder, that is included when published, this is the one seen when someone uses the package in their project. I'm wondering if both are required, and it seems I need a package.json in /src when using npm link.

Comment: Ya, I'm not entirely sure if it's required but is helpful for dependency tracking by things like the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check) CI plugins etc, and devs that may want to re-build the package independently of their own etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have your project set up is a bit unusual. Typically, the project would look like this, with a single `package.json` at the root:

```
.npmignore
package.json
src/
    index.ts
dist/
    index.d.ts
    index.js
```

Instead of only publishing the contents of the `dist` folder, you'd run `npm publish` from the root of the project. The new file [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) tells npm what *not* to publish. If the only thing you want to exclude is `src`, your `.npmignore` would look like this:

```
src
```

Then in `package.json`, set the fields `main` and `typings` to tell Node and TS where to find your code:

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts"
  ...
}
```

(Alternatively, if you *really* just want to publish the contents of `dist`, you could set up another build step to copy your root `package.json` into `dist`. But the publishing strategy I described above is much more typical.)